# Controlling numpy random seed with variable calls to random size

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a simulation that requires the generation of `N` random numbers each iteration. However, `N` varies depending on the state of the simulation. Because `N` varies, the *following* calls to `numpy.random()` yield different results. However, I would like the following calls to `numpy.random()` to be uninfluenced by `N`.

I have been solving this by (1) generating a large random integer before the `numpy.random()` call and then (2) setting the random seed as this integer following the `numpy.random()` call (see below). However this seems clumsy.

Is there a better way to control numpy.random's state that is uninfluenced by the `size` argument?

```
import numpy as np
N=10
# set seed
np.random.seed(0)
# generate N numbers
a = np.random.normal(size=N)
# check its state
print(np.random.randint(1e4))
```

This call to `randint()` returns `2599`

```
# set seed
N = 1
np.random.seed(0)
# generate N numbers
b = np.random.normal(size=N)
# check its state
print(np.random.randint(1e4))
```

This call to `randint()` returns `4859`

Potential solution:

```
N = 10
# set seed
np.random.seed(0)
# generate a large random integer
rand_int = np.random.randint(1e6)
# generate N numbers
b = np.random.normal(size=N)
# reset the seed
np.random.seed(rand_int)
# check its state
print(np.random.randint(1e4))
```

This call to `randint()` returns `5143`, independent of `N`

Comment: I believe the latest changes to the numpy random makes easy to create multiple independent random generators.  But you'll have to read the docs.

Comment: Do you know how many iterations you will have ahead of time?

Answer (score 3):

`numpy.random.*` functions use a single global instance of a PRNG (pseudorandom number generator) that is shared throughout the application. In your code examples `np.random.normal` advances this PRNG a different number of times, so that the `randint` call that follows outputs a different pseudorandom number.

Instead, if different parts of your simulation require a different stream of random numbers, then rather than rely on `numpy.random.*`'s global PRNG instance, use two or more PRNG instances, each initialized based on a common seed.

NumPy 1.17 introduces a [new random number generation system](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html) and includes several facilities for this purpose. These include a `SeedSequence` class for generating multiple PRNG states using a common seed, and a `Generator` class that holds a PRNG. The new system was the result of a [proposal to change the RNG policy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst), which states that `numpy.random.*` functions should generally not be used anymore. This is especially because `numpy.random.*` operates on global state.

The NumPy documentation now has detailed information on [seeding multiple PRNGs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/parallel.html) in the new system. See also "[Seeding Multiple Processes](https://peteroupc.github.io/random.html#Seeding_Multiple_Processes)", from an article of mine about PRNGs.